# How to get the console logs in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I installed my application in iPhone.I put more NSLogs in the application.I tested it and pull the console logs by using iPhone configuration utility.

At some times it's showing half of the logs (Few minutes before). I want the logs that include statements from application installation and launching of app. It is possible to get entire logs?

Comment: This isn't very clear to me what you are asking. I don't think xcode is displaying `half` your logs. You probably have some in `if` statements that don't get called if not true.

Comment: My application having auto log out logic. It should logout the user after few hours of inactivity as i configured. But in client side its getting logged out instantly. Now i gave a logged file to them to find exact scenario of timer getting failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Connect iPhone with you Mac
2. Open XCode -> Window -> Organizer
3. Select Devices Tab
4. Select you device and click Console.

Enjoy Live feed.

Cheers.

Comment: I have some time out issue with client side. I want to know the exact scenario of failure.

Answer (score 1):

`NSLog` outputs to the console in XCode, not on the phone. You can find crash logs in the `Diagnostics` section of the iPhone settings, but not `NSLog` output.